# create a UIWebView and load a website programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, webview

The following is my code. I simply want to load a website page and put a back button on screen. Don't know why nothing shows on the screen.

in .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIWebView *myWebView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *myWebView;
-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender;
@end
```

in .m

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"
@implementation ThirdViewController
@synthesize myWebView;
-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    [myWebView goBack];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.apple.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:myWebView];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]     initWithTitle:@"Back"                                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain                                                                         target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];
}
```

Comment: You missed main thing .where is initialization for myWebView

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Initialize your webView.

```
UIWebView *tempWebview = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:theFrame];
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.apple.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
self.myWebView = tempWebview;
[tempWebview loadRequest:requestObj];
[tempWebview release];
myWebView.delegate=self;
```

Comment: makboney got it in one.
You dont even need to add a back button, just push the view controller from whatever class you were in and if that class contains a nav controller there'll be a back button by default

Comment: yup...dont break the protocol.you shouldn't  use that Back Button in that way.

Comment: Are you talking to me or lav? I thought goBack only worked within a webview opened within a webview

Answer (score 2):

> First Initialize Web view .Write The Below Code In Between [Super
>   ViewDidLoad]; and Nsstring Inisilization.

```
myWebView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
myWebView.delegate=self;
[self.view addSubview:myWebView]
```

> Then Load Request Your Code Will Work.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code into your viewcontroller.m file viewDidLoad method.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.sourcefreeze.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

for complete uiwebview example please refer the below link.

https://sourcefreeze.com/ios-webview-uiwebview-example/