# Swift : how to open an URL in-app

Tags: ios, swift, safari, mobile-safari, in-app

I'm using OAuthSwift, it works perfectly, but when I click on my Login button, it opens a new Safari page. I would like to open the URL in-app, but I'm beginning and I don't know how do that.

**My code :**

```
 @IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {

 doOAuthDribbble()
```

}

```
func doOAuthDribbble(){


    let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    Dribbble["consumerKey"]!,
        consumerSecret: Dribbble["consumerSecret"]!,
        authorizeUrl:   "https://dribbble.com/oauth/authorize",
        accessTokenUrl: "https://dribbble.com/oauth/token",
        responseType:   "code"
    )


    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "dribs://oauth-callback/dribbble")!, scope: "public+write+comment+upload", state: "", success: {
        credential, response in


        // Get User
        var parameters =  Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
        oauthswift.client.get("https://api.dribbble.com/v1/user?access_token=\(credential.oauth_token)", parameters: parameters,
            success: {
                data, response in
                let jsonDict: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)
                println(jsonDict)
            }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
                println(error)
        })
        }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
            println(error.localizedDescription)
    })
}
```

**My Login Page**

[image: My Login Page]

**then, the new safari page**

[image: It opens the safari new page]

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310109/create-a-uiwebview-and-load-a-website-programmically) solves your problem. It's Objective-C, but it can be easily translated into Swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad()` of your `WebViewController.swift`

```
myUrl = someurl
myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: myUrl)!))
```