# Adding address to web view

Tags: swift, webview, hyperlink

I try to add address in several ways, but it's not working all the time. Anybody know the right code?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Dziennik: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: The error is quite clear. Use the correct variable name.

Comment: I'm new in Swift, could you tell me what should i put there?

Comment: Look at the code you posted. What's the actual name of the variable for your `UIWebView` outlet? Use that name instead of `webView`.

Comment: Ok, I did what you said, but I still have issues. Can you help me to write this code? I did some changes, but still a lot of errors. I really would appreciate your help 

<CODE>
let myURL = NSURL(string: “http://www.link.com”);
let myURLRequest:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: myURL!);
myWebView.loadRequest(myURLRequest);
<CODE>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let url = URL (string: "http://google.com")       
let requestObj = URLRequest(URL: url!);
Dziennik.loadRequest(requestObj)
```

Comment: Thank you for respond, I did it, but still there are errors. Can You tell me how to do it properly?
My goal is to make Webviewer to open website.

Comment: i understand that you want to open a url in a webview, but what error you get after you replaces the webview with your property name Dzeiinik ?

Comment: Too much. I think I'm doing it wrong. But I can't find on the web any explanation how it works. Webviewer is on the second view controller. I want it to open websites. If you could tell me what is the formula I would be grateful.

Comment: There are errors for the rest of code. Example: 'NSURLRequest' is not simplicity convertible to 'URLREquest'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

Comment: i edited my answer, please check and send me your feedback

Comment: sorry for the bad alignment, i'm sending from mobile:)

Comment: now it says: " NSURLRequest is not implicitly convertible to URLRequest did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert? "

Comment: answer edited again, sorry for that, i'm not in front of my computer at the moment

Comment: Thank you, everything seems to be ok, but after building it says:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: @SimonWalachowski can you please paste your code? it seems like you don't know how to trace errors, it seems like something else is causing this error

Comment: `import UIKit`

`class ViewController: UIViewController {`
    
    `@IBOutlet weak var Dziennik: UIWebView!`
    
   `override func viewDidLoad() {`
        `super.viewDidLoad()`

       ` let url = URL (string: "http://google.com")`
       ` let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!);` `Dziennik.loadRequest(requestObj)`
        
        
   ` }`

   ` override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {`
        `super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()`
        `// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.`
   ` }`
`}`

Comment: Ok, so I don't know what's the point. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: i apologize for not being able to trace the error with you

Comment: If you know how to do this (implement an answer to project in question) it would be awesome and that's what I need.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276020/xcode-open-url-in-second-view-controller-based-on-button-pressed-in-first-view-c]

Comment: sure, please upload your project and send me link

Comment: I mean, in this question you have demo project. And in answer there is solution. If you could do this for me and send this demo fixed it would be great.

Comment: sure, please allow me sometime, once i finish i'll get back to you with a link, i'll work on it now

Comment: there you go  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100318614/Demo-Swift.zip , make sure to check ReadMe.swift file

Comment: Oh, it's working! You're awesome! Thank you very much. Do you have some tip how i could understand this code? Where should I search? @Sameh
<edit> Oh you left me instructions! Thank you! If I could give You feedback or sth tell me, I'll do for sure!

Comment: I have issues right now, because I want to add new open URL button and it's not working. Says "bad instruction" and I have no clue what's the point

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!))
```

for this:

```
Dziennik.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!))
```

The issue is the name of the property.

Comment: I changed for this:
`let url = URL (string: "http://google.com")`
`let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!); Dziennik.loadRequest(requestObj)`
but it's still now working. (error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION")